# Ontology Plugin Not Available

Tags: java, nlp, ontology, gate

I'm trying to load the Ontology Plugin in GATE 8.6 from https://github.com/GateNLP/gateplugin-Ontology/releases.

The error is:

> Problem while parsing plugin Ontology! java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\intissar\Documents\gateplugin-Ontology-8.5\Ontology.jar (Le
>   fichier spécific est introuvable) Plugin not available!

How can I fix this issue?
Thank you

Comment: So, does the file exist at that path?

Comment: Did you extracted the whole archive `gateplugin-Ontology-8.5.zip
` ? It contains the `Ontology.jar`...